# Is the sentence "Format complete" wrong?

Tags: verbs, idioms, adjectives, omissibility

As a Windows user, I see a message box with the message: `"Format complete!"` when I have finished to format a drive.

According to the dictionary, `complete` is a verb or a adjective.

If it is a verb, the message should be phrased as `"Format is completed!"` or `"Format completes!"`

If it is a adjective, the message should be phrased as `"Format is complete!"`

Why is the message `"Format complete!"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is simply a shortened way of expressing that *The disk formatting is complete* or *The formatting process has completed*.

It isn't a sentence, it's a status indication; think of it as reading a meter or indicator. A human would not report to another human *Fuel empty*, but surely you don't expect your car's fuel gauge to display *Your fuel tank is now only half full*, either.

One of the criticisms Windows has attracted across the years is inconsistency in its interface; in some places, it attempts to be "user-friendly" with conversational text and guides, and in other places it keeps to terse technical language. This very moment as I am writing this, I have seen it: the wordily observed *You just plugged a device into the audio jack*, followed immediately by the perfunctory *Device muted*. I can't fault you for wondering why they don't stick to one or the other.

Comment: Oh come on, nobody is going to chime in to say "No, my fuel gauge should display *Your fuel tank is now half empty*, we're English thankyouverymuch"?

Answer (score 2):

It is a sentence, but not in standard english grammar; it's a slightly [different grammar](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/02/18/the-grammar-of-newspaper-headlines/) of shortened prose which has been used for newspaper headlines for a long time, and other contexts with limited space. It's equivalent to a standard english sentence:

> The format is complete!

But with two changes:

- 3: Omit articles *the*, *a*, *an*
- 8: Omit “be” in its various forms

Leaving the shortened form:

> Format complete!